# Tengo un Error al momento de guardar datos en mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo el problema de que mi codigo en php no guarda los datos que almacenan los inputs, podrian ayudarme a resolverlo ya que soy nuevo en PHP podrian decirme cual es error y como solucionarlo plox

'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Registrarse</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Formulario de registro</h1>
    <form action="registrar.php" method="POST" class="form-register">
        <h2 class="form-titulo">Crea una Cuenta</h2>
        <div class="contenedor-inputs">
            <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="input-48" required>
            <input type="text" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" class="input-48" required>
            <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="Email" class="input-100" required>
            <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario" class="input-48" required>
            <input type="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña" class="input-48" required>
            <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Telefono" class="input-100" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="enviar">
            <p class="form-enviar">¿Ya tienes una cuenta? <a href="index.html">ingresa aqui!</a></p>
        </div>  
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ese es el html

y este es el php (Si conecta a la base de datos) pero al momento de guardar no guarda los datos

```
    <?php
include 'cn.php';
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$contrasena = $_POST["contraseña"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];

$insertar = "INSERT INTO usuarios( nombre, apellido, correo, username, contraseña, telefono) VALUES ([$nombre],[$apellidos],[$correo],[$usuario],[$contrasena],[$telefono])";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
if (!$resultado){
    echo 'Error al registrarse';
}else{
    echo ' Datos guardados';
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: Ayudaría mucho agregues cual es el error que obtienes

Comment: pues no me dice que erro es solo se queda en blanco

Comment: Implementa `mysqli_error` como viene en la documentación para que el error se muestre y lo anexas a tu pregunta: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php

Comment: conectado a la bdYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''usuarios'( nombre, apellido, correo, username, contrasena, telefono) VALUES ('S' at line 1   ese es el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu query deberia quedar asi.

```
INSERT INTO usuarios( nombre, apellido, correo, username, contrasena, telefono) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellidos','$correo','$usuario','$contrasena','$telefono').
```

ademas debes cambiar el nombre del campo contraseña, no puedes usar la ñ ya que no reconocera el caracter y te marcara un error de sintaxis.
Por otro lado debes usar las comillas simple ya que es texto lo que vas a insertar.

Comment: PHP si lo recibe, el error saltara en la base de datos ya que la columna tiene una ñ. tambien depende de como configure su set de caracteres.